# can't resolve @layout/exo_simple_player_view

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I had implemented Exoplayer in my project and it was working perfectly but today it started producing error in my XML layout for the field `app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_simple_player_view"`, saying that **can't resolve @layout/exo_simple_player_view**

Answer (score 8):

After some researches, I understood that it has changed from `exo_simple_player_view.xml` to `exo_styled_player_view.xml`in Exoplayer **version 2.13.2** . After I set this new style value, my error gone

You can check this [Exoplayer github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/layout)

Answer (score 0):

For Exoplayer version **2.16.1** kindly override to **exo_player_view.xml**